# How to efficiently save value to many duplicated tables?

Tags: java, database, oracle, performance, java.util.concurrent

I have an entity named Message with fields: id (PK), String messageXML and Timestamp date. and simple dao to store object into Oracle Database (11g) / MyBatis

Code looks like something like that:

Sevice:

```
void process throws ProcessException {
Message message = wrapper.getMessage(request);
Long messageId;
try {
messageId = (Long) dao.save(message);
} catch (DaoException e) {
throw ProcessException(e);
}
```

Dao

```
private String mapperName = "messageMapper";

Serializable save(Message message) throws DaoException {
try {
     getSqlSession().insert(mapperName + ".insert", message); 
return message.getPrimaryKey();
} catch (Exception e) {
throw DaoException(e);
}
```

Simple code. Unfortunately, load of this method process(req) is about 500 req / sec. and sometimes I get a lock on DB during saving message.

To resolve that problem I thought about multiplication table Message, for instance I will be have five table Message1, Message2 ... Message 5 and during saving entity Message i will be drawing (like a round robin algorithm) table - for instance:

```
private Random generator; 

public MessageDao() {
this.generator = new Random();

Serializable save(Message message) throws DaoException {
try {
     getSqlSession().insert(getMapperName() + ".insert", message); 
return message.getPrimaryKey();
} catch (Exception e) {
throw DaoException(e);
}

private String getMapperName() {
return this.mapperName.concat(String.valueOf(generator.nextInt(5))); //could be more effeciency of course
}
```

What are you thinking about this solution? Could be efficiently? How can I make that better? Where could I make bottleneck?

Comment: I don't get why you would get a lock of the DB due to creations. Maybe some other process that updates values or you might have a full table lock because of a missing index on a foreign key?

Answer (score 1):

Reading between the lines, I guess you have a number of instances of code running serving multiple concurrent requests, hence why you are getting the contention. Or you have 1 server that is firing 500 requests per second and you experience waits. Not sue which of these you mean. In the former case, you might want to look extent allocation - if the table/index next extent sizes are small you will see regularly latency when Oracle grabs the next extent.  Size too small and you will get this latency very regularly, size big and when it does eventually run out the wait will be longer. You could do something like calculate the storage per week, and have a weekly procedure to "Grow" the table/indexes accordingly to avoid this during operation hours. I would be tempted to examine the stats and see what the waits are.

If however the cause is concurrency (maybe in addition to extent management), then you're *probably* getting hot-block contention on the index used to enforce the PK constraints. Typical strategies to mitigate this include REVERSE index (no code change required), or more controversially use partitioning with a weaker unique constraint by adding a simple column to further segregate the concurrent sessions. E.g. add a column serverId to the table and partition by this and the existing PK column. Assign each application server a unique serverId (config/startup file). Amend the insert to include the serverID. Have 1 partition per server. Controversial because the constraint is weaker (down to how partitions work), and this will be an anathema to purists, but this is something I've used on projects with Oracle Consulting to maximise performance on Exadata. So, it's out there. Of course, partitions can be thought of as distinct tables grouped into a super table, so your idea of writing to separate tables is not a million miles from what is being suggested here. The advantage with partitions it is a more natural mechanism for group this data, and adding a new partition will require less work than adding a new table when expanded.

Comment: Those are good ideas but it's possible none of them are relevant here.  The first step should probably be to use a tool like AWR to find out what the database is waiting on (my guess: nothing, it's a network issue).  Thinking in terms of batch vs. row-by-row processing may help solve the problem.  For example, write a simple (possibly parallel) SQL statement to insert dummy rows.  If it can insert 50000 rows per second instead of 500 try to find out why.